# List all methods for a specific variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have not been able to find an answer to this around. I am wondering if there is anyway to call a list of available methods from right inside python.

for example 
if I had this list

```
list1 = ['one',2,3,4,5]
```

I can call `list1.append(6)`

Obviously if I was to download a third party program you can hit tab after the . and it will show a drop down of all methods. But I am wondering if there is something inside python to do something similar so it gives me a list of all methods like list.help or something and it would show.

> .append  .pop .remove etc

Sorry this is a very basic question I was just thinking since I have a hard time remembering all the methods for each type it would save me a little time from looking it up on python.org.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dir() function.
In this case, dir(list1) will show all the available methods concerning list1

Answer (score -1):

in the terminal type python and hit enter and then you can write the method dot and press tab and it will show you a list